# Gradle Version in VSCode running Flutter app

Tags: flutter, gradle

I've install the VSCode, Android Studio, and Flutter in my windows. when I try to launch the android emulator (Pixel 4 API TiramisuPrivacySandbox) and Run the app ( default test app generated in VSCode - click counter) I get an error:

---

> ```
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong:
> A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2.
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.1.2/gradle-7.1.2.pom
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.1.2/gradle-7.1.2.pom
> Required by:
> project :
>
> Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
>
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 31s
> Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
> ```

---

** in gradle-wrapper.properties file, the gradle version is 7.4

```
> distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip
```

** in build.gradle file, the gradle version is 7.1.2

```
> dependencies {
> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
> classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
>     }`
```

** in web or windows devices, it runs without error.

Comment: **`Internet Issue ,Check your Internet Connection`** ----------
if your internet is ok still having this issue then you need to change the internet connection (can use VPN) and try again hope it will work

Comment: Thank you for your help. I try different connections and different VPN. But the error is appears. Why are there two different versions in two files? And which version is used in running the program?